# Angular js $timeout not working properly when i try to cancel and restart it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

i am trying to create a slide of questions using angular js $timeout function, i was able to implement it and it works just fine, but when i try to refresh the slide so it can start again the refresh only work for the first slides as the other slides won't work with the timeout delay time
here is my code below, the main function and the recall function.

```
    $scope.callTime = function() {
        q_len = questions.length;
            $timeout(function () {
                //checking if the question index is still valid
                if (q_indy < q_len) {
                    slides = questions[q_indy].pictures;
                    len = slides.length;
                    console.log(indy);
                    $scope.currentQuestion = questions[q_indy];
                    f_time = parseInt(slides[indy].time_frame);
                    //getting the specific time needed to run this particular slide
                    r_time = f_time - initialTime;
                    if (indy < len) {
                        f_time = parseInt(slides[indy].time_frame);
                        var interval = slides[indy].picture_url;
                        indy++;
                        console.log(q_indy + " " + indy + " " + r_time);
                        //changing to the current picture so it can run for the given time
                        $scope.image = $scope.url.url + interval;
                        if (indy == len) {
                            //checking if the question's slides is out of index so the next question should be loaded
                            q_indy++;
                            indy = 0;
                            initialTime = f_time;
                            console.log(q_indy + " " + indy + " " + r_time);
                            $scope.callTime();
                        }
                        else {
                            //if the slide index is active the next slide should be loaded then
                            initialTime = f_time;
                            $scope.callTime();
                        }
                        //console.log($scope.url.url + interval);
                    }
                }
            }, r_time);
            //time();
        }
    $scope.refresh = function () {
        $timeout.cancel($scope.callTime);
        q_indy = 0;
        indy = 0;
        initialTime = 0;
        r_time = 0;
        len = 0;
        q_len = 0;
        $scope.callTime();
       var e = document.getElementById('myTune');
        //e.pause();
        e.currentTime = 0;
        //e.play;
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the value returned when you call `$timeout` and pass that value into `$timeout.cancel()`. Instead you're passing in the function you used to create the timeout which isn't something that `$timeout.cancel()` knows anything about.

```
var timer = null;
$scope.callTime = function() {
    q_len = questions.length;
    $timeout.cancel(timer); // You probably also want to cancel here
    timer = $timeout(function () {
          // ... rest of your code here ...
        }, r_time);
        //time();
    }
$scope.refresh = function () {
    $timeout.cancel(timer);
    // ... and rest of your code here ...
};
```

Comment: thank you very much...this worked, i only wrapped the timeout function in the timer variable and voila it worked